# CSS image sizing. text on left and image on right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my own web page.

so what i want is text on left and image on right.

problem 1: image will not change the size to 300px
problem 2: i am trying to have the image on the right side, I tried using float and it did not work.

```css
p,
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.top {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.top img {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 35%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="myimage.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="words">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>My name is Jamie Smith<br>I am a student at CSUN<br><br>Welcome, and thank you for visiting my page.
    </p>
    <br>
    <h1>Contact Info</h1>
    <p>jamie.smith@csun.edu<br></p>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    Pages:
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the `<style>` section. Especially all those classes that you use there `top, image, words, list`.

Comment: image size is changed to 300px.. and do u want the image form screen right side and form left side?

Comment: What if you change `<div class="top">
     <div class="image">` to `<div>
     <div class="top">` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
 p,h1{
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
}
.top{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.words, .list{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="image">
    <img  src="myimage.jpg">   
  </div>
  <div class="words">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>My name is Jamie Smith<br>I am a student at CSUN<br><br>Welcome, and thank you for visiting 
        my 
        page.</p><br>
    <h1>Contact Info</h1>
    <p>jamie.smith@csun.edu<br></p>  
 </div>
  <div class="list">
    Pages:
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```css
   p,h1{
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
      }

      .top{
       height: auto;
       background-color: aqua;
       padding: 20px;
       display: inline-block;
       width: 100%;
      }
      .top img{
       float:right;
       width:300px;
       height:300px;
      }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="top">
     <div class="image">
         <img  src="myimage.jpg">   
     </div>
     <div class="words">

         <h1>Welcome</h1>
         <p>My name is Jamie Smith<br>I am a student at CSUN<br><br>Welcome, and thank you for visiting 
          my 
      page.</p><br>
      <h1>Contact Info</h1>
      <p>jamie.smith@csun.edu<br></p>  
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    Pages:
</div>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image gets 300px width, but for making it better add a .image class in your css. Use flex display instead of using float. to set your image on right you can simply add rtl direction to div with top class or put it after div with word class.

```css
p,h1{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
p,h1{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.top{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.top .image img{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="words">

      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>My name is Jamie Smith<br>I am a student at CSUN<br><br>Welcome, and thank you for visiting 
   my 
   page.</p><br>
      <h1>Contact Info</h1>
      <p>jamie.smith@csun.edu<br></p>  
    </div>
    <div class="list">
    Pages:
    </div>

    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/user1-256x256.png" />   
      </div>
 </div>
```